# Program Raspberry PI GPIO on Windows

Tags: python, visual-studio, raspberry-pi, gpio

At the moment I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Professional with Python Tools to program application for my Raspberry Pi. For the moment this is a brilliant combination, because the application can also run on a Windows computer and debug it while in development. After I'm at a point that the application can run on my Pi then I will move the files to the Pi and run it there.

Although today I received a GPIO cable and this open new possibilities to use buttons and controle lightswitches, thus fun stuff. But! Now the problem, on my Windows machine I can use the GPIO library and not see the results of the application, what happens if I push this button, what happens in the code, I really want to debug this and also when using in a bigger application. Everytime moving the files to the Pi and testing them there is not a option.

Is there a application that can simulate the GPIO interface of the Pi on my Windows machine so I can test/debug the application while developing?

Comment: http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=41639

Comment: This question appears to be more adequate for [raspberrypi.stackexchange](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: How did you get the RPi.GPIO library in the visual studio python project?

Answer (score -2):

The nusbio device can give 8 gpios for your Windows machine directly avaialble for .NET languages.